# Cannot Access Global Variable Defined Inside Function

Tags: python, function, global-variables, traceback

I have a program (below) where I have define a function called `function`. I know that you can access variables defined inside the function by defining them as a global variable if you want to access them outside the function. However, in my case, this doesn't seem to work.

```
def function(x):
    
    global num_of_clust, clust_index
    clust_index = np.array([1,2,4])
    num_of_clust = len(clust_index)
    
    return x**2

if num_of_clust >= 1:
    
    print(2)
```

I keep getting an error that says that `num_of_clust` is not defined, which it clearly is inside the function and is defined as a global variable. Does anyone have any insight or suggestions for why this is the case? I have another program with this same issue but it is more complicated so I wrote this test code in order to troubleshoot this issue.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-f629dd1943ba> in <module>
      7     return x**2
      8 
----> 9 if num_of_clust >= 1:
     10 
     11     print(2)

NameError: name 'num_of_clust' is not defined
```

Comment: You never call the function….

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case num_of_clust is defined inside a function that was never called. So you must either call it first or define num_of_clust outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

In this code you can call your function before checking the if condition, then it will work or you can define the variables outside the function.

Comment: Answer is unclear
As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).